# How much do siege engines weigh?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

We are preparing a Pathfinder campaign with some war elements, and one of our party members has skills in siege weaponry. [We found a lot of information about siege engines](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/siege-engines), but there is one big thing missing : their weight.

Even weirder : the weights of all different types of ammunition are given, but the weights of the siege engines are nowhere to be found. This is kind of important since we need to know what we need to transport them.

Where can we find how much siege engines weigh ?

Comment: Are you looking from a game mechanics standpoint or a historical?

Comment: Can the answer be based on other d20 system, like D&D?

Comment: I prefer something coming from the rules themselves, and if the answer is not in any PF rulebook, then maybe something from another D20 system will do.

Answer (score 2):

### It is described, but in Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 handbook Heroes of Battle.

D&D and pathfinder have their differences, however some things like weapon's damage and equipment weight along with it's cost remain similar.

A table on page 67 includes the weight of siege engines.

Comment: I just found the [table of siege engines from HoB](http://www.realmshelps.net/adventuring/combat/siegeengines.shtml#engines), and absolutely everything is different. Even how much the ammunition weigh. Plus some siege engines from PF didn't even exist in D&D.

Comment: There's also a 3rd party splatbook, Cry Havoc, that has siege engines in it.  I think it is for 3.x and not pathfinder, but should be similar.